# how to find out how much of file size served by nginx?

Tags: python, django, file, nginx

so I want to serve some file with django nginx solution. the problem is that many of files which is serving have a huge size and users have some quota to download files. 
so how I can find out how much of file size serving to user? what I mean is that maybe user close download file connection. so how can I find the right size of serving?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With Nginx you can log the amount of bandwidth used pushed to a log file by using the `log_module` but this is not exactly what you want, but can help achieve what you wish.

So, now you will have logs that you can parse to get the file sizes and total bandwidth used and then have a script that updates a database and then you can then authorize future downloads if their limit is reached or within some soft limit range.

[Server Fault with similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/133906/how-to-log-nginx-vhost-bandwidth)

Another option is, making an assumption, keep the file sizes in a database and just keep a tally at the request so when ever they hit a download link it immediately increments their download count and if it is over their limit then just invalidate the link else make the link valid and pass them over to Nginx.

Another option would be to write a custom Nginx module that performs the increment at a much more fine grained level, but this could be more wok than your situation requires.

Comment: ok. thanks @sean. the first solution can be consider as a last solution! :D but about your second option. this is not exactly what i want. let's say the user request a 400 MB file and just receive 2MB and close his connection. so what? I can not reduce his quote with 400MB! I just have to set 2MB of bandwidth usage for this user.

Comment: That is true, I'm not entirely sure how to best handle that with just using the logs itself as it is very coarse grained.